# How to get rid of actual file-name in URL?

Tags: asp.net, iis, url

For instance, this url is `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask`, instead of something like `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask.aspx`. How can I do this?

Comment: [ASP.NET routing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201.aspx) enables you to use URLs that do not have to map to specific files in a Web site. Because the URL does not have to map to a file, you can use URLs that are descriptive of the user's action and therefore are more easily understood by users.

Comment: is asp.net routing a generic feature or specifically a component of MVC (or does that even matter)

Comment: @Gabriel, since an answer using ancient and non-recommended solutions has already been accepted, I'd say it doesn't matter. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a reference to the assembly System.Web.Routing and then add the following to your global.asax file:

```
protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
}

public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.MapPageRoute("",
        "questions/ask/{question}",
        "~/questions/ask.aspx");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this tricks and tools:

http://forums.iis.net/t/1150350.aspx - IIS Solution

http://forums.asp.net/t/979581.aspx - ASP.NET 404 Page solution

Answer (score 0):

If you're question is not specific to aspx pages you can do this with a .htaccess file on any webserver running apache (and mod_rewrite - but that's almost all of them).

See various questions on this site about [.htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.htaccess) or check out many simple tutorials online.

Basically you can put a special file `.htaccess` in the root of the directory you wish to be affected, that essentially say

Instead of `about_us/details.php` you can just use `about_us/details`

This is a very simple example

```
RewriteEngine on 
Options +FollowSymlinks

RewriteRule ^questions/ask ../questions/ask.aspx [L]
```

Answer (score -1):

This happens when the web server implements a handler that maps a given URL pattern to actual content to serve up.

In this site, it's probably from the use of the MVC framework (guessing).

On windows IIS you can use http://www.iis.net/download/URLRewrite